# hostname -I spamming more than one IP address

Tags: command-line, networking

Sometimes I run

```
hostname -I
```

on my machine and got only one local IP returned like `192.168.0.10`, but lately, there is occasions where I type it and got in return both `192.168.0.10 192.168.122.1`.

If I go to my router page and to traffic settings, I don't see this second IP connected to it. How can I go further to investigate what is exactly this other IP, if its related to some other program or even to a security problem?

Answer (score 2):

`hostname -I` is synonymous to `hostname --all-ip-addresses` which means it will show all IP address of all interfaces (except loopback).

In my computer, i have three configured interfaces (one is my physical (bridge) interface, one virtual interface for `lxc` and one virtual interface for `docker`), hence it shows:

```
% hostname -I 
10.0.3.1 172.17.42.1 192.168.6.4
```

From `man hostname`:

> -I, --all-ip-addresses
>            Display  all  network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network interfaces. The
>   loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary
>   to option -i, this option does not depend on name resolution. Do not
>   make any assumptions about the order of the output.

Comment: ok, I understand, but why then I have two internal IPs? I'm not very good at networking but I know that 192.168 Ips are used for lan connections, so why, even hypothetically,  do I have two local IPS? thanks once again

Comment: @anon187 Check the output of `ip a`, you will get a better idea..

Comment: @anon187 you could be connected to your device both via Ethernet and Wi-Fi, for example. There are many reasons. IPs correspond to network interfaces, not to computers.

Comment: you could have installed vmware-player , in this case you could see the following vmnet1, vmnet8 among lo and enp0s25.