# Why am I getting multiple IPs in Hostname -I

Tags: ip

I am trying to get the local ip of the system using `hostname -I`. However, it is showing three IP addresses, instead of one. So, I would like to know what does more than one IP address signify?

Also, I would like to understand how did my system could end up with multiple IP addresses.

Comment: This question has been asked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/750597/hostname-i-spamming-more-than-one-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you see some local IP's as well as an external IP. This is normal. Usually there is 1 local IPv6 address and 1 local IPv4 address. On top of that there should be one public IP.

Local IP's start with:
- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.xxx.xxx
- fe80:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx etc
- 10.0.xxx.xxx